# How to set up a desktop enviroment on android based on Ubuntu Termux?

Tags: ubuntu, termux

note* my device is not rooted

So i've tried to set up a desktop enviroment by using ubuntu on termux based on Xfce4
using an app called AnLinux

i followed the instructions to the point where i've started the vnc server.

the problem is :

1. i didn't know what my username & password is.
2. even though i already start the server, i cant even run the command like 'vncserver-start' or 'vncserver-stop'
   it says : command not found

how do i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the vnc server would of asked you to enter a password, something like: `You will require a password to access your desktops`. The username would be the user that you set the server up with. For ubuntu, I would imagine it to be `ubuntu` or `root`.

Secondly, what package did you install. If you would like to use `vncserver-start` you will need to install the `tightvncserver` package via `apt install tightvncserver`.

Lastly, please check this link https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Graphical_Environment it might help you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, after doing all that steps (on the link) , i faced a black screen with a little white box on it and i don' know what to do anymore...

Comment: @putuasking Ran into a similar issue. You may need to install the x11 package too. Try doing `apt install x11-repo`